# Change event doesn't trigger unless cursor left that area (Chrome)

Tags: javascript

The following works fine when using FireFox, but when using Chrome, the first change event works, but when keep clicking it, the event doesn't trigger unless the cursor left that input area. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks very much!

```
// html
<label for="fontSize">Font Size</label>
<input type="number" name="fontSize" min=10 max=100 step=5>

<div id="myDiv">text</div>

// Javascript
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', myFunc); 

function myFunc(){
    document.querySelector('#myDiv').style.fontSize = this.value + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats how `change` event works for `inputs`. It triggers when the focus is lost. If you want to trigger for pressing any key, you can use `keyup` event or better `input` event.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', myFunc); 

function myFunc(){
    document.querySelector('#myDiv').style.fontSize = this.value + 'px';
}
```

```html
<label for="fontSize">Font Size</label>
<input type="number" name="fontSize" min=10 max=100 step=5>

<div id="myDiv">text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Suren :)